# Need help creating a multi-step form to find a sales rep in a specific area.

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to create a form to find a sales rep in a specific region.  What I want to do is create  a form using php and jquery ajax where the user selects a country or state then when they hit the go button it brings up the next field kind of narrowing down to a specific region.  An example of pretty much exactly what I want is here [Pearson](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/pearsonhigheredus/educator/replocator/requestSalesRep.page?forced_logout=forced_logged_out#)

I assuming I'll have to use ajax to access the MySql database and return the data so that the next field can be brought up.  Can someone help me with how I might go about creating this type of form.  I know their will be database access involved I'm just not sure how exactly to program it correctly

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please show some code of what you have tried. There are hundreds of examples of this question on StackOverflow. Did you try searching before posting? eg. 1 - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=populate+select+php+ajax+mysql 2 - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Creating+and+populating+a+select+dynamically

Comment: I think he wants to know the algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what you have to do, but first i think you want to narrow it down by country->state->city.

ill also assume that you have some basic knowledge of mysql php and ajax.

First thing first.

1- You need to populate the first dropdown with ordinary php
    
    Afghanistan
    United States
    North Korea

so when the user select an item from the drop down fetch_state function will run and it will fetch the selected item from the drop down.
to get the value of selected country

```
function fetch_state(){
var selected=$('#country :selected').text();
   $.ajax({
   url: "someURL",
   data: {selectedvalue:selected}
   ... 
}
```

Ok now that you post the value to the server using this you can fetch the related stated belonging to this country

2- fetch the states from the server based on the selected country. ill assume you can do this

3- Once you get the response back from the server. populate it in the state drop down. also make sure you have a function bind to the state dropdown so when the user further selects a specific state this will fetch the state and send it to server as we did with the province.

4- finally when you get the response from server populate the city drop down.

Need further help please let me know.